# Intersect boolean option in face

Tags: boolean-modifier, intersection

I am trying to use the Intersect Boolean option in Face menu after using a Boolean modifier then joining the object and i cleared the Boolean modifier but when i go to the edit mode as u can see in the video i was selecting the faces individually but i need to select the whole object as i saw in a tutorial and they didn't select individually when they switched to edit mode the object was selected I did as they told first to select the bishop then the cube but i don't know what is wrong in my procedure.[I have attached the video kindly check on it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ce3GZu7UYGIUdq5q3-D2JeqtG8KCbGWq/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Hello please don't use capitals for your title and also your link asks for an authorization

Comment: If you watch a tutorial and do not get same results as what's shown in it, start again from the beginning and follow the instructions more thoroughly. This solves pretty much all problems with something not working same as in a tutorial.

Comment: "I need to select the whole object as I saw in a tutorial" Objects are selected by just clicking on them in object mode, but if you need to select connected geometry in edit mode you can hit  L  while hovering your mouse over desired component of the mesh island you wish to select or Ctrl + L  if you already have some component(s) selected and want to extend selection to all connected geometry. There is also Select similar(Shift+ G ) menu to help with selection as well as everything in Select menu.

Comment: Your link is behind permissions. Please find a way to illustrate your difficulty that doesn't require it. A couple of screen-grabs can go a long way.

Comment: sorry for that i have set open link now and thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

As @Martynas Ziemys told pressing <kbd>L</kbd> did the job thanks